# Porque me envia este error

Tags: php, xampp

estoy estudiando PHP por las noches.

Estoy estudiando PHP con un libro que es algo viejo, al hacer algunos problemas algunos métodos ya están obsoletos, pero continúo intentando aprender.

En la clase de Archivos, al hacer una carga de un archivo por un formulario.

Me envía los siguientes errores

> Warning: copy(BKP.txt): Failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejemplo146.php on line 45
>
> Warning: unlink(BKP.txt): No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejemplo146.php on line 48 ERROR al procesar el
> archivo mi_archivo.txt

Este es mi codigo, espero que me puedan ayudar, quiero saber cual es mi error y porque si copie el codigo tal cual del libro me manda errores.

```
<?php

//Subiendo un archivo al servidor

@$enviar = $_GET["enviar"];
@$archivo = $_GET["archivo"];

if (!$enviar)
{
    //Muestro el formulario

?>
<form method = "GET" action = "Ejemplo146.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
<table border = "0" width = "100%">
    <tr>
        <td width = "100%" colspan = "2"> Ingresa el archivo que desea subir al servidor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width = "21%">
            <p allign = "right">Archivo: </p> </td>
        <td width = "79$"><input type="file" name="archivo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width = "21%"></td>
        <td width = "79%"><input  type = "submit" value = "Enviar" name = "enviar"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
else
{
    //Guardo los datos del archivo
    
    
    //Defino con que nombre guardare el archivo
  //  $directorio = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\directorio\\";
    $directorio = opendir(".");
    $nombre = "mi_archivo.txt";

    $requiere = "$nombre";
    //Copio el archivo que recivo del formulario con el nuevo nombre

    copy($_GET["archivo"], "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\directorio\\".$nombre);

    //Borro el archivo temporal
    unlink($archivo);

    if(file_exists($directorio.$nombre))
    {
        echo "El archivo $nombre ha sido subido exitosamente <br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR al procesar el archivo $nombre <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ese error significa que no existe el archivo, intenta ver si en realidad el archivo esta en la ruta

Comment: No tengo muy claro que los archivos se puedan subir con **GET** y **copy**, sino más bien con el método **POST** y [move-uploaded-file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, los archivos no se pueden subir por GET, necesitas subirlo con POST

```
<form method = "POST" action = "index.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
>
<table border = "0" width = "100%">
<tr>
    <td width = "100%" colspan = "2"> Ingresa el archivo que desea subir al servidor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width = "21%">
        <p allign = "right">Archivo: </p> </td>
    <td width = "79$"><input type="file" name="archivo"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width = "21%"></td>
    <td width = "79%"><input  type = "submit" value = "Enviar" name = "enviar"></td>
</tr>
```

La otra es que para acceder al archivo se usa con la variable `$_Files[]`, xamp y wamp siempre que se sube un archivo lo sube temporalmente en una carpeta, para acceder a ella necesitamos usar la siguiente linea de codigo `$_Files["MiArchivo"]["tmp_name"]` esto te retornara la direccion temporal del archivo en el servidor entonces esa parte del codigo te quedaria asi:

```
@$enviar = $_POST["enviar"];
@$archivo = $_POST["archivo"];
$directorio = opendir(".");
$nombre = "mi_archivo.txt";



$requiere = "$nombre";
//Copio el archivo que recivo del formulario con el nuevo nombre

copy($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], "C:/".$nombre);

//Borro el archivo temporal
unlink($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"]);

if(file_exists($directorio.$nombre))
{
    echo "El archivo $nombre ha sido subido exitosamente <br>";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR al procesar el archivo $nombre <br>";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Estaba colocando el método GET, para ver qué es lo que estaba mandando.

Me aclaraste la duda que tenía ya que no encontraba algún ejemplo básico parecido a este problema.